# django models - best practice for annual subscription management

Tags: django, models

I'm looking for advice on best practice for annual subscription management where the fees may change each year.

I have a Membership and MemshipYear models as well as the User models. Each membership category (membership.category) has an annual fee which may be different. Members will be able to download pdf invoices for membership fees at any time once logged in.

The pdf is generated at the time of request and the data is taken from the membership model. Therefore if the membership fee changes after one year the invoice would be caluclated with this figure and not the fee for that year.

One thought I had was to use price banding i.e A-F, and have a price band for each category for each year.

I reckon there's a better way.Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically, the membership itself should have a price, since that inherently belongs to the user. On creation, you would set this value from the category. Then, whenever you need to get the current price the user is paying, you pull it from their membership, instead of the variable price on the category.